# Nissan X Trail 2001 engine RPMs increase, but vehicle does not accelerate, has no power

Tags: automatic-transmission, nissan, power, rpm, x-trail

2001 Nissan Xtrail. After driving for more than 20 minutes, the car seems to have less power. The rpm will go way up, but the car is slow. Rpm can go near the redzone, yet I’m still driving at 10-25kmph. A temporary fix is switching the car off and waiting 20 to 30 minutes. The problem will reoccur after another 20 minute drive. Can anyone help, I haven't taken the car to any repair shop, I want to know if there is anyone out there who have had this problem, and how did they fix it

Comment: It sounds to me like the transmission is slipping. Have you pulled the dipstick to see if the fluid is up to level? How does the tranny fluid smell? If there's a burnt smell, the clutches are probably shot (or getting there quick). When the tranny is cold (or cooler), it can have better grab with worn clutches. Then when it's hot, slippage can occur. The 20-30 minutes of rest is enough to allow it to cool down and operate fairly much normally.

Comment: Someone told me that might have been fluid, but I did refuelled gearbox oil, then it still happened

Comment: If your fluid was low for an extended period, it could have caused accelerated wear on the clutch components. This would mean that even after refilling the fluid that the clutch would still need replacing.

Answer (score 0):

i think it has shift selinoids .probably 2.if in pan and got to hot they will not shift correctly .must be r&red .had this happen on caddy.

Comment: I’m not sure about Nissan, but generally failing shift solenoids will trigger limp-mode and a CEL right?

Answer (score 0):

It would slip all of the time If it was low on fluid or the clutches were worn and shutting it of for 20-30 minutes would not help it any.

To me, it sounds like the converter is malfunctioning and overheating. The next time it happens, downshift manually and see if there is any difference in the vehicles acceleration, if not then I would have the converter inspected by a reputable transmission shop.